# Use JSDOM to get text from a specific tag (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, html, request, response, jsdom

HTML Response:

```
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <span style="font-size:30px">Name:</span>
    <span style="font-size:25px;border-radius: 10px;">John Doe</span>
    <h1>Stats</h1>
    <div>
      <p>info1</p>
      <p>info2</p>
      <p><a href="https://link.com">info3</a></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

would I use `querySelector()` to retrieve the link in the  tag and the John Doe in the 2nd span tag? If so how would I get the exact tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMParser` as follows:

```js
const response = `<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <span style="font-size:30px">Name:</span>
    <span style="font-size:25px;border-radius: 10px;">John Doe</span>
    <h1>Stats</h1>
    <div>
      <p>info1</p>
      <p>info2</p>
      <p><a href="https://link.com">info3</a></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, "text/html");
console.log(doc.querySelector("a[href]").href);
console.log(doc.querySelector("span:nth-child(2)").textContent);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can edit the specific span element then try this:

- Set an ID attribute on the second span element
- Use the `getElementById` to reference the element
- Then use `textContent` to get the text

```js
const name = document.getElementById('name').textContent

console.log(name)
```

```html
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <span style="font-size:30px">Name:</span>
    <span style="font-size:25px;border-radius: 10px;" id="name">John Doe</span>
    <h1>Stats</h1>
    <div>
      <p>info1</p>
      <p>info2</p>
      <p><a href="https://link.com">info3</a></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```